Authenticate Azure Email client before sending email
I have code to send email from python azure email client.
client = EmailClient.from_connection_string(
        "https://mydomain.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=XXXXXXXXXX"
    )
...
...
client.begin_send(message)

If the token is not valid, it raise error when it reach to client.begin_send.
Is there any way to know if the key is not valid before reach to client.begin_send? can we call any other method to know if token is valid or not ?

Based on the documentation for this SDK/class, it doesn’t seem like it - at least, nothing built into the SDK itself seems to provide this functionality. Even so, how does it change how you approach things? Why not just catch the exception thrown using begin_send and handle it the way you want then? Am I missing something?

yes, that is current scenario, but after database entry, we are are sending email. I want to check if there is something wrong, then I dont want to start any database operation. I cant send email first before database. I can do transaction, but I want to check in case we can avoid that.

Sounds like you should create your database entry within a transaction, then rollback the transaction on failure to send the email and commit the transaction otherwise.

yes, that is what I am doing now, but in case if I can avoid that operation, then its good.


Authenticate Azure Email client before sending email

Thanks @esqew and I do agree that this is the functionality of the sdk, that only when the client calls, then only we can get to know if its working or not. I use exceptions to handle this like below:
from azure.communication.email import EmailClient as cho

rith_con = "https://rithdomain.communication.azure.com/;accesskey=XXXXXXXXXX"
try:
    client = cho.from_connection_string(rith_con)
    
    tst = {
        "hello":"rithwik"
    }
    client.begin_send(tst)
    print("Connection established Rithwik")
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Error in Connection establishment Rithwik: {e}")

Output:

Or you can also roll back the data transactions as you were doing.

what will happen with client.begin_send(tst) when connection string is correct? Where it will send this data?

I just tested the connection, need to write correct code and connection to send the data
